# queryset Django ? small questions

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-queryset

i am making a function of search something from my database. 
i am not sure about the way of returning results.

it does not come out anything..

but on CMD, i can see user's Email who has searched Mother_language because of

```
print(MyUser.objects.filter(Mother_language__contains=Mother_language))
```

in view

this is my model

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True, null = False)

    Nationality =models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Country_choice,null = False)
    Mother_language = models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Language_list,null = False)
    Wish_language =models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices= Language_list,null = False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images',blank=True)
    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','Nationality','Mother_language','Wish_language','picture']
```

this is my form

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields = ('Mother_language','Nationality')
```

this is my view

```
def index(request):
    print "entered"
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        Mother_language = form.cleaned_data['Mother_language']
        Nationality = form.cleaned_data['Nationality']
        MyUser.objects.filter(Mother_language__contains=Mother_language)
        MyUser.objects.filter(Nationality__contains=Nationality)
        print(MyUser.objects.filter(Mother_language__contains=Mother_language))


        return render(request, "LanguageExchange/index.html", { "MyUser": MyUser})
print(form.as_table())
return render(request, "LanguageExchange/index.html", { "form": form,})
```

this is my index.html

```
 <form id="form" method="get" action="{% url 'index' %}"enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{form.as_table}}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to capture the result of the queryset into a local variable and send *that* in the context rather than the `MyUser` - The class itself.

Change

```
MyUser.objects.filter(Mother_language__contains=Mother_language)
```

to

```
myuser_qs = MyUser.objects.filter(Mother_language__contains=Mother_language)
```

and then

```
return render(request, "LanguageExchange/index.html", { "MyUser": MyUser})
```

to

```
return render(request, "LanguageExchange/index.html", { "MyUser": myuser_qs})
```

Comment: Wait..where are you displaying the content of the queryset in the template?

Comment: i missed {{MyUser}} in my html